# Comparing boolean matrices

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, pseudocode

I have a little problem. I need to compare one two-dimensional array filled with ones and zeros (lets call it Matrix A - zeros actually represent blank spots and ones are positions of football players on the field) against lots of other matrices filled differently (but again, just ones and zeros) and the result should be some indication which of the matrices is most similar with the Matrix A. By similarity I mean similarity in distribution (or positioning) of the players on the field - so the matrix with players postition the most similar to the matrix A will be chosen for further stuff.

Could somebody help with this algorithmic problem ?

I'm writing it in c++ but pseudo-code would suffice. The problem is just a comparison algorithm. The best would be if the output of the comparison function would be something like `similarity coefficient` which I can store in an array and later choose the most similar matrix using it. But I just cant come up with some algorithm for that similarity comparison.

EDIT: some clarifications about similarity and algorithm copied from my comments below -

Matrix A - [Matrix A](http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D) , Matrix 1 - [Matrix1](http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D%7D) , Matrix 2 - [Matrix2](http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D), Both have 1 change in comparison with Matrix A, but for me - matrix 2 must be "more similar" - because player is standing closer to its position in matrix A

Matrices are considered to be around 8x6 or something like that, it needs to be reasonably fast - it will be computed every game cycle (so every 20ms or so..), and there will be 5 players on each side.

Comment: You're going to need to define "similarity" a lot more robustly than the above vague description if you want to come up with an algorithm

Comment: Well the most similar matrix would be the one with the players standing closest to the positions (or in some cases exactly on the positions) in the Matrix A.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you added some examples to your question, along with the required "similarity" measure that you would expect in each case ?

Comment: I don´t really know how to explain the similarity measure, i thought it is somehow obvious :) But I will try with some examples:

Matrix A - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D

Matrix 1 - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D

Matrix 2 - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Matrix 1 would have better similarity coefficient.. U got the basic idea?

Comment: There is one obvious metric: how many moves would it take to change one of the matrices into another by having the players walk around. However, that would be difficult to compute.

Comment: Did you have any ideas for a similarity measure (even bad ones?). Also, since I'm not much into football, is there any additional similarity info you get from the game rules (e.g. if player moves left/right, that is more similar than if he moves forward/backward). My last question: how big do you expect the matrices to be during real program usage (and how often do you plan to compare them)? You could edit your question to add this info so people know are you looking for a _fast_ method, a very _precise_ or something different (it's always a trade-off)

Comment: The metric suggested by Peteris is actually not all that difficult to compute; you just need to compute pairwise distances between players on the two matrices, and the solve an [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). Since there are probably not so many players, this should be fast.

Comment: @FalkHüffner - depending on what you mean by "fast" :) If you want to use the comparison once (precompute) or once in an iteration - it is fast. If you need to use it several (hundred) times per iteration, on every new matrix in several (hundred, thousand...) iterations, some faster approximation of Peteris' idea, or a completely different simpler measure might work better, I think.

Comment: Hello, to clafiry some things - Matrices are considered to be around 8x6 or something like that, it needs to be reasonably fast - it will be computed every game cycle (so every 20ms or so..)

Comment: @FalkHüffner - could you please describe your suggestion little deeper?

Answer (score 1):

A zero/one matrix is *not* a good representation for your needs.

You care about the *total player [displacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_%28vector%29)*. Since the number of players is constant it is possible to represent a game state as a matrix whose rows correspond to players and columns corresponds to field coordinates. So, for example, for two players {{1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,1}} will be {{1,1},{3,3}}. Given two games state matrices A, B, you can treat them as vectors and compute vector similarity with any distance measure ([like these](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html), also see [C++ library](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/cluster.pdf)). One simple option is [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity): `dot(A,B)` (in your case the norms are constant.)

Comment: Hello, number of players is constant.

Comment: @Jam, in that case, it is simpler. Updated.

Comment: So you are suggesting something like this? - Make matrix representations of both game states like you suggest and then compute cosine similarity for each pair of vectors (for each two "rows" in both matrices) - and then maybe.. sum the results? Sorry if I dont quite understand, my english is not so good.

Comment: @Jam, what you wrote is possible but less efficient. You don't have to treat each row separately, you can treat the matrices as flat vectors for computational efficiency. If you use cosine similarity, the two approaches will give different results, but both may be good. If you use Euclidean distance, the two approaches are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: so I should just re-write the matrix as one dimensional array? And also - is there some C++ library equivalent of those distance measuring functions that you posted?

Comment: I will try this solution tomorrow, really thanks for your help (the question above still lasts :) )

Comment: @Jam, added [C++ library](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/cluster.pdf), but this isn't necessary. Many times the choice of metric doesn't matter very much.

Answer (score 0):

An idea for a possible simple algorithm, though not very robust, but which could be enough in your case:

1. Perform a **XOR** of corresponding cells in two matrices to get a boolean matrix where `1` means there was a *difference* between the two original matrices, and `0` means that cell was *identical* in both matrices.
2. **Sum** all the cells in the result matrix. The lower the score (sum), the more similar the original matrices were.

This would provide you, for every two matrices, the number of cells that are changed.

In the example you provided in the comment, according to this algorithm, Matrix 1 would get a score of `2` and Matrix 2 would get a score of `8`, which means that Matrix 1 is a lot more similar to `A` than Matrix 2.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but i forgot to mention one important thing - this solution would not solve my problem properly, because matrices with for example one change (one position of player is different) would both have score of 2, but it didnt take in account the distance of the player from the position in Matrix A - meaning that it doesnt matter where is the player standing - it will always have score of 2... And well, that is what is really problematic about it, taking in account the distances. - Sorry I didnt make it clear in my question.

Comment: What I mean: 
Matrix A - http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D

Matrix 1 - http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D

Matrix 2 - http://www2.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D

Both have 1 change in comparison with Matrix A, but for me - matrix 2 must be "more similar" - because player is standing closer to its position in matrix A

Comment: @Jam, Yes, you are right. My solution indeed doesn't take that into consideration, but I won't delete it just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for distance between 1s it will be a little work.
AND the two arrays, then sum - this gives the number of positions where two 1s have distance=0.
Now generate a mask by shifting the original in all 4 directions, OR them together to give MASK1.
AND MASK1 then sum to give the number of positions where distance=1.
You can generate 4 more masks for diagonal shifts.
You can weight the sums for different distances.

For example, if your original array is

 `0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 1 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0`

Then MASK1 would be

 `0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 1 0 0

 0 1 0 1 0

 0 0 1 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but I am not really sure if I understand that corectly - could you please describe it in little more detail?